# Do i need an ATV for Brussels airport transit for change of planes?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, belgium

I am Indian passport holder holding BRP (British) travelling to India with a brief stopover, transit only for change of flights at Brussels airport. Do I have to get an ATV?

Comment: What is an ATV? Airport transit visa?

Comment: Can you confirm if your itinerary is on a single ticket? British residence permit bears no relevance to visa requirements anymore since the British withdrawal from the European Union.

Comment: @xngtng a US green card exempts its bearer from the ATV requirement, as do residence permits of several other non-EU countries.  Was the UK not added to that list when it left the EU ?

Comment: @phoog Apparently not, I was also surprised, but the German Mission in the UK explicitly warns about this situation : https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/airport-transit-visas/2442170.

Comment: @JoErNanO I read it as "All Terrain Vehicle", and thought "No, I'm pretty sure there are roads there"...

Answer (score 4):

Indian citizens don't need an Airport Transit Visa (ATV) for Belgium. There are four countries in the Schengen region which require ATV from Indian citizens. They are France, Germany, Spain and Czech Republic.

You can find information on the websites of the individual Schengen countries. Belgium's website refers to the general EU website which has published a "table" in this regard. Here is the link to that:

https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-09/Annex%207B.pdf

Comment: +1 but as always it should be noted that a "regular" visa will be needed if the passenger needs to retrieve bags or to clear passport control for any other reason.